# Multiple of Hamiltonian Cycles

Tags: graphs, hamiltonian-circuit

I'm currently confused whether a graph should contain strictly one distinct Hamiltonian Cycle. (given that **[1,2,3,4,1]** and **[2,3,4,1,2]** are the same).

I was wondering if, by definition, there can be multiple distinct Hamiltonian Cycles in a graph? something like **H1 = [1,2,3,1]** and **H2 = [6,7,8,6]**

can someone kindly confirm?

(*addt'l sources and references would really be great so I can dive in deeper*)

Cheers!

Comment: In your second example, H1 and H2 can't be Hamiltonian cycles in the same graph since a Hamiltonian cycle includes every vertex exactly once. In your first example, the two cycles could be distinct Hamiltonian cycles in a complete graph on 4 vertices.

Comment: I see.. so for the second example, H1 and H2 would simply be called *cycles* right? is there a distinct name for cycles that doesn't contain same vertices?

Comment: If you want to, you can call them *vertex-disjoint cycles* (i.e. they don't share *any* vertices).

Answer (score 2):

Recall a Hamiltonian cycle visits each vertex of a graph exactly once. Thus, the cycles **H1** and **H2** in your second example can't be Hamiltonian cycles in the same graph.

In your first example, the two cycles could be distinct Hamiltonian cycles in e.g. the complete graph on 4 vertices. That is to say, there can definitely be multiple Hamiltonian cycles in a graph.

If you care about naming conventions, you can call two cycles that don't share any vertices *vertex-disjoint cycles*. Similarly, two cycles can be *edge-disjoint* if they don't share edges.